# Convex combination of $\frac{1}{x}$ inequality

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $0 < x_1 \leq ... \leq x_n$ and $\sum \alpha_i = 1, \alpha_i \geq 0$. Show
$\sum \frac{\alpha_i}{x_i} \leq \frac{x_1 + x_n - \sum \alpha_i x_i}{x_1 x_n} $. Since the left side looks like a convex combination and $\frac{1}{x}$ is convex I started by using that, giving me $\sum \frac{\alpha_i}{x_i} \geq \frac{1}{\sum \alpha_i x_i}$. Here I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated doesn't have to use convexity.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the minimum value of the right side minus the left side. The derivative wrt $x_1$ is $\leq 0$ so it gets no bigger if you increase $x_1$ to equal $x_2$. Then the derivative wrt $x_2$ is $\leq 0$ so it gets no bigger if you increase $x_2$ to equal $x_3$. Continuing in that way you find the minimum occurs when all the $x$s are equal, in which case the left side equals the right side.

Or, if you don't like induction,
$$
   \frac{x_1+x_n-\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i}{x_1x_n}
   - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{x_i} =
   \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{(x_j-x_{j-1})
      \Bigl(x_n-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}a_ix_n-\sum_{i=j}^n a_ix_i\Bigr)}
    {x_{j-1}x_jx_n}.
$$
Each term is self-evidently nonnegative due to the ordering of the $x_j$s and the fact that $x_n$ is greater than or equal to any convex combination of the $x_j$s.